# How to use a wildcard for a field to sort many shp

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, sorting, wildcard

I want to use a wildcard for a field so as to sort a group of shapefiles.

All of them have the same columns but there is one column in each of them with only the first 4 characters common.

Is there a solution for that either with python or with iterator in modelbuilder?

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

This is the code i have written until now

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/W/Sik/Point"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("EV*", "point")
fields = arcpy.ListFields(fcs, "AVGA*", "Double")
for fc in fcs:
    for fiel in fields:
        arcpy.Sort_management(fc, fc_sort, [[fiel, "ASCENDING"]]
```

Comment: Are you trying to find fields in a shapefile or all the shapefiles that have that field? To find a field use ListFields("wildcard") to return the field names that match, for example ("asdf*") will find all the fields beginning with asdf.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson i have 10 shp that have a column that starts from "AVGA" and after the first 4 characters it is differentiated. So i want to write a script that will sort these shp based on that field. I just don't know how to write this.

Comment: How would you sort? Do you want to sort the values in the field or the names of the fields... to get the field that starts with use arcpy.ListFields(FC,"AVGA*") which will return a list of fields that start with "AVGA"... perhaps if you included your code so far we could work out what it is you're trying to do and can help in a more specific way.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson ASCENDING as i have written already in code. The first, i want to sort the all the values (except FID) based on these fields in each shapefile. The first shp will have a field like AVGA20 that i will use, the second shp will have a field like AVGA_TR10 etc. With the code i have written above i am trying to sort based in fields which start from AVGA* all my shapefiles. Didn't it help at all?

Comment: Don't sort shapefiles... it will **break** them. The row order is not fixed and controlled by the driver, if you change the order of the rows they will no longer work as shapefiles (or the attributes will belong to the wrong geometry if they work at all). If you want a sorted table copy the dbf file and open with Microsoft Excel (or equivalent) and do an advanced field sort.

Comment: any correction for my code?

Comment: Apparenty sort_management creates an output table... so long as you don't overwrite the existing it shouldn't break anything. I've not used that command so perhaps create a list of lists and use that to sort; I don't know how to control which is sort first/next/last, do you understand how to control the sort order? If so I can help with creating a list of lists to sort.

Answer (score 3):

As the tool [Sort_management](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000057000000) creates an output table with the fields sorted this should be ok to do.. just remember that as a shapefile it wont stay sorted if you edit it; the edited row moves to the end of the table. From the description the tool expects a list of lists (or tuples I think), so to sort on multiple rows you need to create a list of lists.. in python you start with a blank list:

```
fieldSortList = [] # new empty list
```

Then make a new list and append it to the existing list:

```
fOpt = [fiel,"ASCENDING"]
fieldSortList.append(fOpt)
```

After a few iterations it looks like this (a list of lists):

```
[[fiel,"ASCENDING"],[fiel,"ASCENDING"],[fiel,"ASCENDING"]]
```

Putting that into your code:

```
import arcpy, os
#from arcpy import env# don't need this if you're implicity specifiying arcpy.env

arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/W/Sik/Point"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("EV*", "point")

for fc in fcs:
    fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc, "AVGA*", "Double") # the fields for this feature class

    if fields: # if any matching fields found
        fieldSortList = [] # new empty list

        # iterate through the fields for this feature class
        # appending the field name and sort type to the list
        for fiel in fields:
            fOpt = [fiel,"ASCENDING"]
            fieldSortList.append(fOpt)

        # make the out name, change this here to suit your needs
        fc_name,fc_ext = os.path.splitext(fc) # breaks the file name/extension up into two variables
        fc_sort = fc_name + "_sorted" + fc_ext # abc.shp => abc_sorted.shp

        # do the sorting to the output feature class
        arcpy.Sort_management(fc, fc_sort, fieldSortList)
```